# Are the shortcut keys in Sublime Text 2 the same on OS X and Windows, if you exchange Cmd with Ctrl?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, sublime-text

I am using Sublime Text 2 on OS X, and I really like that editor. Now I need to explain the way Sublime Text 2 works to someone who is using Windows, and of course there's no `Cmd` key there. I guess that the equivalent would be `Ctrl`, but I'm not sure if this works for Sublime Text 2 in all cases.

Does anybody know if OS X and Windows key bindings are the same, if you simply exchange `Cmd` for `Ctrl`?

Or does anybody know where you can look the shortcuts up, so I can manually compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the key bindings are the same, but not all of them, so you can't just automatically exchange <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>.

However, with Sublime Text 2 it is quite easy to look up all the default key bindings that come with the editor. Navigate to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` to open up the `Packages` folder. Go to the `Default` subfolder and open the `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` and `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` files, and set the syntax to `JavaScript -> JSON` for readability. These files contain all of the key bindings that come with Sublime (but not the ones that plugins may install), so you can search for an OSX binding in one file, get the `"command"` name, then search for that in the Windows file to get its equivalent.

Note that in the OSX bindings the Command key is called `super`.